# Динамическое изменение цены при изменении количества товара

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь. Есть сайт, типа магазин, там 30 товаров, все на одной html странице. Они не берутся из базы. Нужен скрипт, который изменяет цену товара при изменении его количества.
Нашел такой скрипт, он плюсует и минусует количество товара.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.minus').click(function () {
                var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
                count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
                $input.val(count);
                $input.change();
                return false;
             });
             $('.plus').click(function () {
                var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
                $input.change();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Но как сделать чтобы при этом автоматически менялась и цена - не знаю. При этом, чтобы внизу еще менялась итоговая цена всех выбранных товаров. Сразу скажу, я не особо разбираюсь в javascript, моя сфера - php. Это задание нужно сделать в кратчайшие сроки, поэтому времени изучать js совсем нет. Заранее благодарю за понимание и помощь.

Comment: вы надеюсь в курсе, что нельзя полагаться на цену сгенеренную js ?

Comment: повесьте событие рассчитывающее цену товара исходя из базовой на 

    $(document).on('change','тутселектордляинпутаколичества',calculate_price);

    function calculate_price() {
        var $input=$(this),
            count=$input.val();
        //тут код рассчитывающий цену и вставляющий в поле цены
    }

я если честно сомневаюсь что вы и в php достаточно понимаете, т.к. вообще говоря вы не предоставили достаточное количество данных, ни как задается цена ни как ее нужно менять

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уточню. Товар НЕ берется из базы. Т.е. все 30 штук прописаны вручную. Цена - это просто строка в div. Надо сделать так. Посетитель заходит на эту страницу, выбирает кнопками (+ -) какой товар ему нужен и в каком количестве, при этом автоматически считается стоимость товара и общая стоимость, а потом эта информация отправляется на другую страницу заказа.

Comment: то что не из базы понятно, непонятно из какого именно div. где описана цена, как считать стоимость, короче говоря **давайте пример разметки**, желательно в jsfiddle сразу, чтобы нам не переносить туда самим.

Comment: Вот ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/MrNix21/penT2/

Comment: Все, спасибо, вопрос решен))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё как я и говорил, вот функции расчета суммы по количеству и общей суммы.
Я использовал jquery минимальной версии 1.7.2, вместо 1.5 которая у вас была, на 1.5 я ничего делать не буду, уж извините за столько лет можно и обновить.

```
var order={};
$('.catalog-tab').on('change','.number input',calculate_price);
function calculate_price() {
    var $input=$(this),
        count=$input.val(),
        price=parseFloat($input.parents('td').prev().children('input').val()),
        sum=parseInt(price*count),
        item=$input.parents('tr').children('td').eq(2).text(); //тут
    $input.parents('td').next().text((print_price(sum))).data('sum',sum);
    if (count===0) {
        delete(order[item]); //тут
        calc_sum();
        return;
    }
    order[item]={sum: sum,count: count};
    calc_sum();
}
function calc_sum() {        
    var sum=0;
    for (var key in order) {
        sum+=order[key].sum;
    }
    $('.catalog-tab').find('td').last().text(print_price(sum));
}
function print_price(v) {
    return ((v*100)+'').replace(/(..)$/,',$1 р.')
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так, теперь как я понял, эту функцию надо прописать в <head>. Jquery скачал, поставил. Но почему то не работает. Уж не судите строго, такой вот я нуб в js(((

Comment: ну учитесь, удачи... прописать надо в функцию в document.ready

я там забыл еще одну вещь, щас в ответе исправлю

Comment: Круто, заработало, огромное спасибо!

Comment: И еще вопрос, а теперь эти данные можно отправить на другую страницу? Т.е. какой товар выбрал посетитель и в каком количестве?

Comment: соберите форму из объекта order и отправьте её, я делать не буду, т.к. уже далеко за рамки бесплатного кодинга зашел.

Comment: Упс, почему то общая сумма обнуляется (вместо старого значения на его место ставится сумма последнего выбранного товара), а не складывается из уже выбранных товаров. Так и задумано?

Comment: в двух местах немного пропустил :) но вы наверное сами уже нашли. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/penT2/2/